# Definition of the present perfect tense

Tags: american-english, present-perfect, british-english

I am a learner of English and I have been learning it for the last few months. I wrote a definition of **the present perfect tense**. Please check the definition and let me know that I have been using it perfectly or not. I am a little bit confused about it.

**The Present Perfect Tense:**

> 1->An action started in the past but it has just finished or maybe not
>   (as per me both options are possible).
>
> 2->An action started in the past and it has just finished but its
>   result matters in the present.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My knowledge of tenses](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18826/my-knowledge-of-tenses) though there is no answer

Comment: This tense indicates either that an action was completed (finished or "perfected") at some point in the past or that the action extends to the present:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it. The present perfect is simply an event in the past that is either still happening, just finished, or important to the present. It could also be used when the date is unknown.

She's just finished baking a cake *(something just finished)*
It's been happening for a while *(something that has happened in the past and may still be happening in the present)*
She's learnt a lot *(the date is unknown but may still be happening)*

Etc. Your definition is cool. This just gives a few examples to try and help you gain some confidence with it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful. One question for you as you wrote 'She's just finished baking a cake'. My question is that can we use cake as a countable noun? I think it should be a piece of cake, please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: You can say one cake, two cakes, more cakes etc,
And you can say one piece of cake, two pieces of cake, three pieces of three cakes, etc.